# How do you add to dictionary using append?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I've almost at my end goal with this. I want the user to type in a list of names 
and then the position of the word to be saved in the dictionary if the 
word is not already been saved. For example Ali, Dan, Martin, Ali will read 1 2 3 1 .

```
Names= input("Type all names you want to include: ")
##str.casefold
Names = Names.split()
AllWords = len(Names)
dict = {}
pos=0
for j in enumerate(Names):
    for j in range(AllWords):
        if Names not in dict:
          dict.update(key,Names)
print(Dictionary)
```

Expected output would be:
Matt Mike Jerry Jon Sarah Matt    1 2 3 4 5 1  #names and positions

Comment: Can you paste your expected output ?

Comment: Please not that dictionaries are unordered collections, I'm not sure if you would rather like to use a list instead... Also, what are you doing with this j variable you're assigning in both nested for loops? This looks very strange.

Comment: updated for loop with Names. And expected output.

Comment: I think what you need is a 'list' not 'dict'

Comment: Your loops seem redundant. You are not using the elements you are iterating over. Also why use enumerate if you are going to ignore what it yields?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do the following in order to add more key value pairs in existing or empty dictionary.

```
Dictionary[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries don't have an `append(value)` method, use `update({key: value})` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Dictionaries in python does not have any method called **append** , instead make use of **update**

```
dict.update({key:value})  or dict[key] = value
```

in the second case if key is not present it will add a new entry, if key is there it will update the value corresponding to that key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: dict.update takes a dict or an iterable of key/value pairs as its argument: update(key, value) will raise a TypeError.

Comment: Sorry went wrong in hurry.. Thanks for remainding . :-)